# PostgreSQL: How to get all points in certain radius

Tags: postgresql, geospatial, earthdistance

I'm using Postgresql 9.3 and iv'e installed cube and earthdistance extensions.

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://johanndutoit.net/2013/01/07/searching-in-a-radius-using-postgres.html), so i have a simple events table with 4 fields: id, name, lat, lng.

Now i'm trying to run this query, to get all events within 1 km radius:

```
SELECT events.id, events.name FROM events WHERE earth_box(31.789225, 34.789612, 1000) @> ll_to_earth(events.lat, events.lng);
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
20:59:34 Kernel error: ERROR:  function earth_box(numeric, numeric, integer) does not exist
  HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So i ran the same thing with casting:

```
  SELECT events.id, events.name FROM events WHERE earth_box(CAST(31.789225 AS float8), CAST(34.789612 AS float8), 1000) @> ll_to_earth(events.lat, events.lng);
```

and i get :

```
   21:16:17 Kernel error: ERROR:  function earth_box(double precision, double precision, integer) does not exist
                                                              ^
      HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O.K, finally after couple of hours i got it :)

Apparently the tutorial i was working with was outdated, the correct syntax is this:

```
SELECT events.id, events.name FROM events WHERE earth_box(ll_to_earth(31.789225,34.789612), 1000) @> ll_to_earth(events.lat, events.lng);
```

Comment: Ah oopsie that's my bad. Will try to update it tonight or this tomorrow.

Comment: @JohannduToit, you haven't updated your penultimate query (`SELECT events.id, ...`). Thanks for the tutorial though :)

Comment: ll_to_earth not treated as a function. bad luck. :(

Comment: Please provide us the table creation script. Ii wanna see the datatypes

Comment: @anduplats You realize this is a 5 years old post?!