# How to query a postgres database to get all points within a 10km radius of certain coordinates

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, geolocation

I have a database of shops and in that database I have coordinates for these shops saved. I would like to get the list of shops in a 10km radius however I am not sure how to write the Postgres query since I am using Postgres database.

My database :

[image]

I am trying to add the query to a springboot geolocation microservice :

Repository code :

```
@Repository
public interface SellerGeolocationRepository extends CrudRepository<Seller_Geolocation, Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM seller_geolocation_ms WHERE 
   // get coordinates that are in the vicinity
", nativeQuery = true)
        public Set<Seller_Geolocation> findAllSellersInRange(double longitude, double latitude);

    }
```

SellerObject :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "seller_geolocation_ms")
public class Seller_Geolocation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2L;

    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String zipCode;
    private String town;
    private String address;
    private Long sellerId;
}
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77072/return-all-results-within-a-30km-radius-of-a-specific-lat-long-point

Comment: @Erent Why aren't you using classes like `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point` to persist geospatial data instead of simply persisting two double numbers? In that case you could easily make geospatial queries

Comment: I wasn't aware of com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point, if I were to use it how would I make the query

Comment: You need to use `hibernate-spatial` and install `postgis`. I'm going to post an answer using these in spring-boot

Comment: @Erent look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501246/cant-execute-spatial-query-with-spring-and-hibernate-5-0) This is how you should implement it.

Comment: @Omid do u have an example of how to use hibernate-spatial and install postgis, I have installed them but I can't seem to get a good explanation on how to use it

Comment: Have you tried using Criteria Queries? (https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries)

Comment: Here's some background information to the mathematics: https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work you will need to install postgis :

> brew install postgis

afterwards you will need to install postgis on your postgres database "**seller_geolocation_ms**":

```
   1. $ sudo -i -u postgres
   2. $ psql
   3. postgres=# \c seller_geolocation_ms;
   4. seller_geolocation_ms=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
   5. \q
```

After these steps postgis should be installed on your database. then the next thing to is to write the query on your Springboot repository interface like this:

```
@Repository
public interface SellerGeolocationRepository extends CrudRepository<Seller_Geolocation, Long> {

    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM seller_geolocation_ms WHERE ST_DWithin(cast(seller_geolocation_ms.location as geography),ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(?2, ?1),4326), 10000);", nativeQuery = true)
    public Set<Seller_Geolocation> findAllSellersInRange(double longitude, double latitude);

}
```

To get a more indepth understanding of how ST_DWithin please follow this link :[here](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer @DivxExtract !! In its current form, it didn't work for me, but it DID work once I switched out the ?2, ?1 parameter binding to named parameters :longitude :latitude

Answer (score 3):

You can use the haversine formula, using your current coordinates (target_latitude_deg/longitude) and the column name (latitude_deg, longitude_deg), both expressed in degrees

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM myTable
WHERE acos(
       sin(radians(target_latitude_deg)) 
         * sin(radians(latitude_deg)) 
       + cos(radians(target_latitude_deg)) 
         * cos(radians(latitude_deg)) 
         * cos( radians(target_longitude_deg)
           - radians(longitude_deg))
       ) * 6371 <= 10;
```

Alternatively, have a look at the PostGIS extension

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE ST_Dwithin(geom, st_point(target_longitude, target_latitude,10000);
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand the haversine formula and how to pass my current coordinates and query longitude and latitude from my db

Comment: This is not a good solution to the problem in this case. The point of using frameworks like spring boot combined with hibernate-spatial is not to get involved in low level details of how geo-spatial formulas work. OP should use built-in features of those frameworks not a raw sql query.

Comment: @Omid fair enough... though without PostGIS I am very curious to know how it could be leveraged by the framework

Comment: @JGH Well it's not possible without postgis.

Comment: @Omid :-/ so it's either an important change for the OP (for the best), or the provided raw SQL alternative

Comment: @JGH what is geom in the last query

Comment: the name of the column (geometry type) that you would have created/populated

Comment: To avoid doing a full search, first search for the points in a bounding box around the certain point with the length of 20 km. This search can use normal indices and will return a much smaller set of records the database will evaluate afterwards with this expression.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Postgres [earthdistance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/earthdistance.html), ther's also an example mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147954/postgresql-how-to-get-all-points-in-certain-radius)
However, you can use [Postgis](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#idm2065) which has rich geospatial functions.
If you want to calculate at business logic, use Haversine formula as explained in @JGH answer above.